# How to run a docker container from sbt before tests start?

Tags: scala, docker, sbt

When I google this question, it's all about creating a docker container with sbt. But I want the opposite: Running a docker container (or docker compose) from sbt.

Comment: https://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-execute-exec-external-system-commands-in-scala - try running it as a bash command

Comment: Since you said that it is for tests, checkout [**testscontainers-scala**](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-scala)

Answer (score 1):

If you should run a container for a test I can suggest [sbt-docker-compose](https://github.com/Tapad/sbt-docker-compose), you can set a timeout after which the test will be execute.

It's a sbt plugin, with `sbt dockerComposeUp` you can put all the containers running.
Otherwise with the command `sbt dockerComposeStop` all the containers will stop.